# Connecting traditionalists and vegetarians this Thanksgiving

Tags: riddle, seasonal, word-sequence

For the holiday in the United States a word association riddle to connect traditionalists and vegetarians across the table.  Each clue line associates with a word or short phrase, that word and the next clue associates with the next word.  Happy Thanksgiving!

> Bird bird bird, bird is the word
>
> What some Europeans thought it was
>
> 20 shillings at first
>
> 20 shillings always
>
> Like that but more fists and less hammers
>
> What you develop when you do
>
> Becomes this delicious vegan entree
>
> A different, seasonally appropriate vegan entree

Additional hint

> The last is a brand name

Hint 2

> The title works to connect the last and first lines

Hint 3

> There is more than one option that would fit line 7 but the original one I'm thinking of sounds devilish. The other, if it quacks, might also be the answer.

Hint 4

> The 6th is vegan but ironically is the elimimation focus of a different special diet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following are the intended answers. Of course others have posted most of them first. (As it happens I did 1-4 independently, but I got 5 and 8 from Rand's answer.)

```
Bird bird bird, bird is the word
```

> TURKEY (obviously)

```
What some Europeans thought it was
```

> GUINEA FOWL (related and similar-looking bird)

```
20 shillings at first
```

> GUINEA (first word)

```
20 shillings always
```

> POUND (connected via shillings)

```
Like that but more fists and less hammers
```

> KNEAD (rough synonym)

```
What you develop when you do
```

> GLUTEN (as the clue says)

```
Becomes this delicious vegan entree
```

> SEITAN (is made from gluten)

```
A different, seasonally appropriate vegan entree
```

> TOFURKEY (only connection is that it's another vegan entree)

Comment: All complete!  The alternative for #7 is rot13(ZBPX QHPX), which is made from #6 and fits the theme

Comment: @user662852 My feedback would be that I think the flow in clues 1-5 is nice and natural, but then the last three clues are more obscure and the connections less clear. My upvote on the puzzle stands though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think it's all OK. The step I actually like least is 4 to 5; the way I do the action in 5 isn't much like the action in 4 and doesn't really use fists.

Comment: "Fingers" instead of fists maybe?

Comment: Yes, that would be better, though the action still isn't very much like 4.

Answer (score 4):

I have a partial answer I'd like to proffer

```
Bird bird bird, bird is the word
```

> Turkey (Traditional Christmas Food)

```
What some Europeans thought it was
```

> Guinea Fowl ([thanks to Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91633/56669))

```
20 shillings at first
```

> Guinea ([thanks to Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91633/56669))

```
20 shillings always
```

> Pound (there were 20 shillings in a pound)

```
Like that but more fists and less hammers
```

> Knead ([thanks to Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91633/56669))

```
What you develop when you do
```

> Dough (This is what you knead)

```
Becomes this delicious vegan entree
```

> Dough Balls (apparently a lot of establishments make Vegan ones of these)

```
A different, seasonally appropriate vegan entree
```

> Vegan Stuffing Balls (Season related)

Comment: 1 and 4 are right

Comment: Thanks @user662852 - have updated last 3 (based on the correct 2,3,5 answers by Rand al'Thor)

Answer (score 4):

*Bird bird bird, bird is the word*

> TURKEY (a type of bird traditionally eaten in an American celebration called [Thanksgiving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving)).

*What some Europeans thought it was*

> GUINEAFOWL ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey_(bird)#History_and_naming)).

*20 shillings at first*

> GUINEA ([a coin once worth 20 shillings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinea_(coin))).

*20 shillings always*

> POUND ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sterling)).

*Like that but more fists and less hammers*

> KNEAD (pounding with hammers, kneading with fists).

*What you develop when you do*

> BREAD (from kneading dough).

*Becomes this delicious vegan entree*

> LENTIL LOAF? TOFU?

*A different, seasonally appropriate vegan entree*

> TOFURKY? ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tofurky)) - thanks @Exal.

Comment: All so far are right

Comment: @user662852 I think I've made some more progress.

Comment: 1-5 are now right

Comment: @user662852 Since I'm neither vegan nor American, I'm now reduced to Googling for [vegan Thanksgiving dishes](https://thekindlife.com/blog/2012/11/15-vegan-thanksgiving-entrees/). Lentil loaf maybe?

Comment: I think the last one is Tofurky.

Comment: 1-5 and 8 are right

Comment: rot13(Cbffvoyl #6 vf "tenva", bar gnetrg bs erzbiny bs gur xrgb qvrg?) - as per latest hint